# Typescript generic class type with static methods

Tags: typescript, generics, static-methods

Suppose I have these classes

```js
abstract class Animal {
    public static getSound(): string {
        throw new Error("Abstract animal has no sound");
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    public static getSound(): string {
        return "Woof";
    }
}


class Cat extends Animal {
    public static getSound(): string {
        return "Meow";
    }
}
// Other animal classes...
```

And I want to write a function that takes a generic **subclass** of Animal, i.e. **not** instance of subclass, as a parameter and calls the corresponding static method `getSound`. This is what I've tried so far.

```js
interface ClassType<T = any> {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}

const getAnimalSound = <T extends Animal>(type: () => ClassType<T>) => {
    return type().getSound();  // Property 'getSound' does not exist on type 'ClassType '.
};

console.log(() => Dog);  // should print "Woof"
console.log(() => Cat);  // should print "Meow"
```

But I'm getting the compile error `Property 'getSound' does not exist on type 'ClassType'`.
The meaning of the error is obvious, I didn't set up the types correctly, . How should I go about doing this, **without redesigning the classes**?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ClassType` should be declared as

```
type ClassType = typeof Dog | typeof Cat;
```

And the `getAnimalSound` should be transformed into:

```
const getAnimalSound = (type: ClassType): string => type.getSound();
```

Now, if we call

```
console.log(getAnimalSound(Dog));
console.log(getAnimalSound(Cat));
```

their sounds can be heard.

The issue in the original approach is that the `static` methods belong to the class object and they cannot be invoked on an instance, so we need to access the type reference.

In fact, the static "inheritance" in the original approach does not make sense, because these methods are invoked as `Animal.getSound()`, `Dog.getSound()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps the type for `getAnimalSound` is not accurate.

The argument should be a function which returns `Animal` constructors, not *instances*. Looks like you're aware of that, as you've written `ClassType<T>` to be a type that represents a constructor for instances of type `T`. That is almost right, but the critical thing is `ClassType<T>` only has information on the constructor signature, it has lost all the information on the static members of the class! This is what leads to your error.

One little known feature of typescript is that if a type `T` represents the type of an *instance* of a class, then the type `typeof T` (as weird as that looks) represents the *constructor type*, including all static members!

So your type for `getAnimalSound` could be simplified:

```
const getAnimalSound<T extends typeof Animal>(type: () => T) => {
    return type().getSound() // No Error!
}
```

Using that, seems like you will get the desired result!:

```
console.log(getAnimalSound(() => Dog)) // Logs: "Woof".
console.log(getAnimalSound(() => Cat)) // Logs: "Meow".
```